# How can I avoid error in MatchIt exact matching procedure?

Tags: r, matching

With the MatchIt package I want to perform an Exact Matching procedure. Doing this I get an error, even if the [vignette](https://imai.princeton.edu/research/files/matchit.pdf) (p. 6) claims:

> There are no additional options for exact matching.

Here an example:

```
library(car)
WeightLoss1 <- WeightLoss
WeightLoss1$group <- as.integer(ifelse(WeightLoss1$group == "Control", 0, 1))

library(MatchIt)
matchit(group ~ wl1 + wl2 + wl3 + se1 + se2 + se3, method = "exact", data = WeightLoss1)
```

Error message:

```
Error in weights.subclass(psclass, treat) : No units were matched
```

Bug? Feature? Misuse?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: In your small datasets there are no units matching by the specified variables. Try with a smaller number of matching variables, for example  `matchit(group ~ wl1 + wl2 , method = "exact", data = WeightLoss1)`

Comment: It's only an example, but the error also occurs with my real data with 100k individuals.

Comment: Try reducing the number of matching variables. May be there are no matching units using your set of variables.

Comment: @marco-sandri You were right, there were simply no exact matching units even in the 100k! Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by *@MarcoSandri* in the comments, there are trivially no matches.

We could confirm this by a check function.

```
chkMtch <- function(d, grp.var) {
  spA <- lapply(split(d[, -grp.var], d[[grp.var]]), as.matrix)
  spB <- lapply(spA, function(x) split(x, row(x)))
  m <- t(outer(spB[[1]], spB[[2]], Vectorize(function(x, y) 
    all(identical(x, y)))))
  out <- spB[[1]][which(apply(m, 1, all))]
  return(if (length(out) == 0) message("no exact matches found" ) else out)
}
```

Using the example of the question `matchit` yields:

```
library(MatchIt)
fml <- group ~ wl1 + wl2 + wl3 + se1 + se2 + se3
matchit(fml, method="exact", data=WeightLoss)
# Error in weights.subclass(psclass, treat) : No units were matched
```

and the check with our function:

```
chkMtch(WeightLoss[all.vars(fml)], grp.var=1)
# no exact matches found
```

Let's illustrate this with a small example by creating data with obviously completely different groups.

```
(d1 <- data.frame(matrix(c(rep(1, 12), rep(2, 16)), ncol=4, byrow=TRUE, 
                       dimnames=list(NULL, c("y", paste0("x", 1:3)))),
                group=factor(rep(0:1, c(3, 4)))))
#   y x1 x2 x3 group
# 1 1  1  1  1     0
# 2 1  1  1  1     0
# 3 1  1  1  1     0
# 4 2  2  2  2     1
# 5 2  2  2  2     1
# 6 2  2  2  2     1
# 7 2  2  2  2     1

matchit(group ~ y + x1 + x2 + x3, method="exact", data=d1)
# Error in weights.subclass(psclass, treat) : No units were matched

chkMtch(d1, grp.var=5)
# no exact matches found
```

If we now intentionally match one row of the second group with the first,

```
(d2 <- as.data.frame(t(replace(t(d1), 21:25, 1))))
  y x1 x2 x3 group
1 1  1  1  1     0
2 1  1  1  1     0
3 1  1  1  1     0
4 2  2  2  2     1
5 1  1  1  1     1  # match
6 2  2  2  2     1
7 2  2  2  2     1
```

we get:

```
matchit(group ~ y + x1 + x2 + x3, method="exact", data=d2)
# Call: 
#   matchit(formula = group ~ y + x1 + x2 + x3, data = d2, method = "exact")
# 
# Exact Subclasses: 1
# 
# Sample sizes:
#           Control Treated
# All             3       4
# Matched         3       1
# Unmatched       0       3

chkMtch(d2, grp.var=5)

# $`2`
# [1] 1 1 1 1
```

***Data***

```
data("WeightLoss", package="carData")
WeightLoss$group <- ifelse(WeightLoss$group == "Control", 0, 1)
```